# How to access REAL querystring param in javascript with URL rewrite in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, query-string

I am trying to `alert` the querystring param in jquery because i need that `ID` on a page load so that i can create some html elements when the control is loaded. I cant seem to access the parameter as the URL rewrite in place and URL looks diff then the original one.

## Original URL

```
www.somesite.com/camping?ProductId=2457&ism=0&cl=PURPLE
```

## URL seen in browser

```
www.somesite.com/camping/travel-mug-16oz-double-wat-with-adapter-p2457.aspx?ism=0&cl=PURPLE
```

now, how do i access the ProductId querystring value in Jquery.

## Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var param = getParameterByName("ProductId");
     alert(param) // shows PURPLE as cl in URL is set to cl=PURPLE

});

function getParameterByName(name) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                      results = regex.exec(location.search);
      return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

EDIT:

here is the screenshot when i am trying to access the Querysting object on serverside..

[image]

Comment: I don't exactly know what URL rewrite is but the URL given to the browser does not have a ProductID query string. Javascript cannot see onto the server without the server providing access, would you be able to access this via Ajax?

Comment: that is what i am trying to understand... how can i access the actual URL via jquery?

Comment: As far as Javascript is concerned the first URL never existed, it has only been given the second one, if you have the "Actual" URL stored on the server you can access this via [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is attempting to access the value from the querystring, which no longer exists as it has been rewritten on the server.

You can use a regular expression to dissect the rewritten URL, no jQuery required. Assuming your `productId` is always prefaced by `-p` and is immediately followed by `.aspx`, then this will work:

```
var url = 'www.somesite.com/camping/travel-mug-16oz-double-wat-with-adapter-p2457.aspx?ism=0&cl=PURPLE'
var matches = url.match(/-p(\d+)\.aspx/);
var productId = matches && matches[1];
console.log(productId); // = 2457
```

`productId` will be `null` if there are no matches to the regex.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/QeSXn/)

Comment: Yes @Rory, i think this is the case... productId will always be prefaced by p- BUT not sure about the .ASPX thing BUT i assume this is the case...